# How to keep a Karma server running, but not run tests only until I manually tell it to?

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I would like run Karma without having to shut down the server on every single run. I know that you can turn off single run and have watch running. However, I don't want my tests to re-run on every single save and would like to trigger them manually.

Is it possible to keep a live Karma server but prevent it from running my tests on every single save?

Comment: Maybe you should look into some sort of macro system (depending on your OS) so you can create a keyboard shortcut to launch karma.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I can turn `autoWatch` in the config file, which I knew how to do before. After that, if you are running tests through Chrome, you can simply refresh the debug page.